# How to get URL in Razor View in the form /Controller/Action/Id/.../QueryString

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form which passes the current url to a controller action so that it redirects the user back to the page he/she previously was.

Currently, I am concatenating the Controller, Action and QueryString as follows;

```
var currentUrl = $"/{ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]}/{ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]}/{Context.Request.QueryString}";
```

In my controller action I have the following;

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
else
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

I feel as if this is rigid and that there is probably a method which already does this but I can't figure out what it is.  The approach I was using does not accomodate for instances like `/Home/Index/1/2019/...?message=hello`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add parameters to routing.Here is a demo:

startup(The quantity of your parameters(`/1/2019/...`) needs to be less than or equal to the quantity of `/{id?}/{id1?}/{id2?}/...` ):

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}/{id1?}/{id2?}");
            });
```

View:

```
<h1>
    CurrentUrl:@Context.Request.Path@Context.Request.QueryString
</h1>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: This is working for most pages, but returns "/" for Home/Index/...

Comment: It is because you use `localhost:xxx`,so the path is '/'.

Comment: Thank you, I had an extra space somewhere, it works now :)